# Why isn't there a "cite" option under questions and answers like there are for other Stack Exchange Sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, citation

I'm currently working on a slideshow presentation for my Network Programming class in which I'm compiling all the substitution techniques I have found while independently studying different things, and I found cool substitution techniques like this [answer](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/8718/10807), but I have noticed there is no "cite" option between the "Share" and "Edit" option like there is on other Stack Exchange sites.

Is this an option that is turned on by this SE moderators, or how does that work? Mostly, I really enjoy how easy it generates Bibtex like this citation example from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4670477/1119495):

> @MISC {4670477,
> TITLE = {Approaching Type theory and Category Theory as a starting point in the study of mathematics?},
> AUTHOR = {Mateus Galdino (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1166059/mateus-galdino)},
> HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
> NOTE = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4670477 (version: 2023-04-01)},
> EPRINT = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4670477},
> URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4670477} }

For a technical site like this one, I feel as if this feature would be helpful and improve its sharability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks so much for your patience while I followed up on this. As of today, I've updated the site settings to allow this feature. Please let me know if you come across any issues with it!

Comment: This is excellent! Our appreciation to all the staff who helped get this accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

I agree this could be a useful feature. There's a nearly decade old [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189213/504837) about this that suggests the citation feature is only available on a few (perhaps only two) sites. I don't think mods control it. It may be something that needs to be customized in the code running OR SE.

Comment: [Catija mentioned this is possible if we collectively wish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354147/make-the-cite-option-on-a-question-shown-everywhere-on-the-network?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1183649_354147), maybe something to discuss!

Comment: So, do we discuss it just among mods or is there a mechanism to put it up for a vote of all users? I would never use the feature myself, but I don't see any harm, and the amount of screen real-estate required is pretty minimal.

Comment: I think can discuss between us, there is positive reception and can't think of why it would be a bad idea